# How do I retrieve the last record entered in Zoho using their REST API

Tags: php, rest, zoho

From the help section [REST API (View Records)](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/rest-api/rest-api-view-records-in-view.html#sample_request) I was able to retrieve all the records entered into my Zoho form in JSON format from my php script. They have a sample request there that I emulated.

However, this returns the **ENTIRE** record set but I would like to retrieve only the last one entered and use it in my code. I have not found any way to do this at all. Downloading the entire JSON file of all records will be problematic as my data set grows.

UPDATE: This is the request from HTML for retrieving the dataset.

```
    <form method="GET" action="http://creator.zoho.com/api/json/my_application_name/view/my_report_name">
    <input type="hidden" name ="authtoken" value="****">
    <input type="hidden" name ="zc_ownername" value="ownername">
    <input type="hidden" name ="scope" id="scope" value="creatorapi">
    <input type="submit" value="View Records">
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you provide the retrieval code, it will be much easier to answer your question.

Comment: @zhon I have posted the retrieval code now. It is exactly as in the REST api tutorial page. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want try set a criteria and use a date value, better still use the 'limit' and set value to 1:

```
<input type="hidden" name="criteria" value="(StartDate == zoho.currentdate")">
<!-- below was tested and works -->
<input type="hidden" name="limit" value="1">
```